# CSS to position text based on Top of text?

Tags: css, typography

[image]

When I change the size of a font in CSS, how do I make it so no matter what size the font is (from 12px to 200px), that the "Cap Height" (pic) of the text will always 'visually' have 10px padding on top?

Otherwise what I'm doing is every time I change the font size, I have to go back and reposition the top/margin-top etc.

Here's what I have:

CSS:

```
#header .statement {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 960px;
}

#header .statement h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 160px;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #141414;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML sample:

```
<div id='header'>
  <div class='intro'>
    Stuff before the statement
  </div>
  <div class='statement'>
    <h3>
      <p>A Statement</p>
    </h3>
    <div class='large_spacer'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like with `line-height: 0`:

[alt text http://ilove4d.com/ex/css-typography.png](http://ilove4d.com/ex/css-typography.png)

This is with `line-height: 1`:
[alt text http://ilove4d.com/ex/css-typography-2.png](http://ilove4d.com/ex/css-typography-2.png)

If I change the `font-size` from 160px to 20px, the white space proportionally gets smaller...  How do I get around that?

Note: it's adding like 20px extra whitespace, even if margin:0;padding:0;...

Comment: Have you tried setting the padding-top of the containing element?

Comment: it looks like I have to set `line-height: 0.8` in order to set the correct base.  Then I can use padding... why is that?

Comment: It's probably adding the 20px you're talking about because you've stuck a <p> tag inside a <h3>. If you haven't reset the margins and line-height on the <p> tag, that's what would happen. Better yet, just get rid of the <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean "on top" of the cap height, and not somehow inside the cap height margin, then you can apply the CSS padding to either the font element or its parent container:

```
<span class="something">Web Typography</span>

span.something {padding-top: 10px;}
```

OR...

```
<div class="something"><span>Web Typography</span></div>

.something {padding-top: 10px;}
```

One of the approaches will be suitable depending on what other styles you are applying.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding-top:10px to #header .statement h3 {}

edit:

did you reset the values for #header .statement h3 p {}?

Comment: didn't work, I still have 20px whitespace that's coming from somewhere unknown.  If I set line-height to 0, it to where the bulk of the letter starts.  Line-height must play a role, no?

Comment: Well, text is always centered vertically in a line box which is like setting vertical-align to 50%. So depending on the size of the font, it will overflow the line box.

Answer (score -1):

> Otherwise what I'm doing is every time
>   I change the font size, I have to go
>   back and reposition the top/margin-top
>   etc.

Why don't you set `bottom` and `margin-bottom` of the elements above and below that text instead? In this way, you won't have to modify the text styling, the gap will be there always.

Also why in the world, you can touch a font-size of more than 36px? In any case, you could also use the `line-height` style for that like `line-height:30px;` or whatever value.